# IF statement in MySQL as an Event

Tags: mysql, if-statement, events, sql-update

Sorry that I'm completely clueless about this. But what I'm trying to do is this:

Under a table, I have two columns, `group_1` and `group_2`. I want to run a daily event where if `group_1` and `group_2` have the same value `12`, `group_2` becomes empty.

This is the awful piece of code I have:

```
BEGIN
IF group_1 = 12 AND group_2 = 12 THEN
            UPDATE group_2 SET group_2 = ''
        END IF;
END
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

**UPDATE 1:**

Someone suggested using CASE function. This is what I came up with. Still no luck:

```
SELECT group_1, group_2,
CASE
    WHEN group_1 = 12 AND group_2 = 12
    THEN SET group_2 = ''
END
FROM core_members;
```

Comment: you can use CASE function bro

Comment: @Strawberry I swear I tried my best. That was the only piece of code I could come up with.

Comment: @chandu could you give me an example? Maybe post it as an answer? I am a real beginner here, and boy, I'm struggling. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: @chandu I just edited my main post. Am I getting close? It still doesn't work.

Comment: I can only refer you again to my original comment

Comment: @Strawberry I have provided almost everything I can. What is missing for it to become a Minimal Reproducible Example? What I'm getting as an error? If so, syntax error.

Comment: UPDATE core_members SET GROUP_2 =' ' WHEN member_group_id = 12 AND mgroup_others = 12

Comment: bro i think i will work

Comment: Explaining the link defeats the point of providing the link, no?

Comment: @chandu I'm still getting a syntax error with that, for some reason =(

Comment: @Hilas Please comment the error

Comment: I have updated the main post with the correct columns. Sorry if that confused you @chandu

Comment: @chandu it says "SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN group_1 =12 AND group_2 =12' at line 1 */"

Comment: sorry @Hilas its not WHEN ,WHERE

Comment: UPDATE core_members SET GROUP_2 =' ' WHERE member_group_id = 12 AND mgroup_others = 12

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you SO MUCH, @chandu! It looks super simple but it's a pain for a complete newbie like me. Would you like to post that as the answer?

Comment: UPDATE core_members SET group_2 ='' WHERE group_1 = 12 AND group_2 = 12

Comment: i posted it  @Hilas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE core_members 
SET group_2 = '' 
WHERE group_1 = 12 
  AND group_2 = 12
```